# sizeof() operator returns different value for an array and pointer to an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Below is a C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func(int a[])
{
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
}

int main()
{
  int arr[10];
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(arr));
  func(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that the **sizeof()** operator returns **40**  when I use **sizeof(arr)** but **8** when I use **sizeof(a)**.
What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: The reason is that the sizes of the two things are different. You should clarify why you expected the result to be the same.

Comment: i expect the result to be 40 in both cases

Answer (score 2):

Simple, yet confusing: A function parameter such as `int a[]` or `int a[42]` gets *adjusted* to `int* a`. `func(int a[])` is adjusted to

```
void func(int* a)
```

Here, `a` really is no more than a pointer. So `sizeof(a)` is `sizeof(int*)`.

On top of that, arrays can *decay* to pointers in many situations, such as when you pass `arr` to `func`. That allows this to happen

```
func(arr);
```

even if `func`'s parameter is a pointer.

Comment: If I dont pass the array as a function parameter and take a local pointer pointer to it then also the problem doesn't get solved

Comment: @ashishbhat The size of a pointer is the size of a pointer. Nothing can change that. Although I'm not sure what "the problem" is.

Comment: is there a difference between an array name and a pointer?

Comment: @ashishbhat There is no way to know the size of the array within your function and if you want it then you need to pass an additional parameter to the function `func(int *a,size_t num_of_elements){ ...}`

Comment: @ashishbhat An array name may *decay* to a pointer in many situations. One of them is if it is passed as argument to a function whose parameter is a pointer (such as `func`.) But arrays and pointers are different things (as you can see from running your program.)

Comment: @ashishbhat Yes, [there is a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/) between an array name and a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing size of a "pointer" to the actual size of an array.